# What the difference between these two statements?

Tags: c

```
int a = 5;
int b = 6;
int c;
```

**First Statement:**

```
c = a > b ? 1 : 0;
```

**Second Statement:**

```
c = (a > b);
```

What is the difference between the two above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both statements are equal as in C language there is no concept of boolean. So, `true` is represented as 1 and `false` is represented as 0.

Refer https://www.le.ac.uk/users/rjm1/cotter/page_37.htm

Comment: Actually, `false` is represented by 0, but everything else is represents `true`. So, -3, 0.5, and `'0'` are all true.

Comment: @AustinWBryan While values such as `-3`, `0.5` or `'0'` are considered to be true (or rather non-false), the result of a boolean expression is always either `0` or `1`.

Comment: I know. I just wanted it to be out there that the other values represent `true`, because this had that information missing.

Comment: C language has the concept of boolean (`_Bool`), however the result of > is an `int`, and either `1` or `0`

Comment: C very well has a conc ept of boolean. A comparions yields a boolean result, represented by an `int` with values `1` and `0`. Boolean logic just means binary logic; the representation is not implied (how do other languages represent "true" and "false"? Python e.g. uses objects).

Answer (score 8):

On a normal compiler there is absolutely no difference (except that the first has more keystrokes and second has unnecessary parentheses `(...)`). On some really badly optimizing compiler, one form or the other can be slower.

A true result from `x > y` is represented as `1` and false is represented as `0`. Quoting *ISO/IEC 9899:201x Committee Draft April 12, 2011 N1570*:

> Each of the operators `<` (less than), `>` (greater than), `<=` (less than or equal to), and `>=` (greater than or equal to) shall yield `1` if the specified relation is **true** and `0` if it is **false**.) The 
>   result has type `int`.

And `a ? b : c` is an expression that, if `a` evaluates to true gives the value `b` otherwise `c`.

Thus result-wise the 2 are identical. Actually, if you compile this code and disassemble it you'd notice that the compiled code might not be different either:

```
int test1(int a, int b) {
    return a > b;
}

int test2(int a, int b){
    return a > b ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Compiled on GCC 4.7.2, x86-64, with **debugging on** (`-g`) - which should ensure here that all the optimizations are disabled as much as possible - then disassembled with `objdump -d foo.o`:

```
0000000000000000 <test1>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   7:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
   a:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   d:   3b 45 f8                cmp    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  10:   0f 9f c0                setg   %al
  13:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  16:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  17:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000018 <test2>:
  18:   55                      push   %rbp
  19:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  1c:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  1f:   89 75 f8                mov    %esi,-0x8(%rbp)
  22:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
  25:   3b 45 f8                cmp    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  28:   0f 9f c0                setg   %al
  2b:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
  2e:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  2f:   c3                      retq
```

You can see the code for the 2 functions is perfectly identical; you cannot deduce which one compiled to which. The expression is on 3 lines:

```
   d:   3b 45 f8                cmp    -0x8(%rbp),%eax
  10:   0f 9f c0                setg   %al
  13:   0f b6 c0                movzbl %al,%eax
```

The first one compares `b` to `a` and set the processor flags appropriately. The second one sets `al` (the lowest byte of register eax/rax) to 1 if the result was "greater" (note that the comparison was inverted above!), 0 otherwise; And the 3rd, `movzbl` zero-extends a byte to 32-bit integer, as we're returning an *`int`* here.

Comment: Just out of curiosity of a non "compiler" expert, could you explain how and in which circumstances the first statement could possibly be faster than the second? I get that the second might be faster but can't see how the first could. +1.

Comment: Well, it would be a really bad compiler indeed. It is just theoretical, but if you needed a **jump** to happen for `?:` on a certain architecture then you need a **jump** to happen for `>` as well, to set 1 or 0 properly. So it could be that the jump would be ordered differently and cause branch prediction failures.

My point is that making such statements about what the code is generated from C source code is very bold.

Answer (score 3):

In the first, `a>b?1:0`, you assign the integer value `1` or `0` to the variable `c`.

In the second, `(a > b)`, you assign the boolean result of the comparison to the variable `c`.

Semantically a big difference, in the real world no difference at all since in C the value for true is `1` and the value for false is `0`. So `c` will get the value `1` or `0` either way.

Answer (score -1):

**Difference is in the execution and not in the result**. A language like C which is used extensively in embedded systems; execution is an important consideration.

In case of statement 1 the result of expression `a>b` will be evaluated and based on the output of that a value would be assigned to the variable `c`. In second case the output of expression `a>b` is directly assigned.

Execution wise second statement is more optimal. First statement is decision based while second is a simple assignment. It doesn't require a mention still you have more flexibility in case of statement one as you can do a lot more with it other than assigning 1's and 0's

From a hardware perspective running **statement one would require more cycles than statement 2**.

Comment: There is no difference in execution if you do not use a really bad compiler.

Comment: Yes but we are not talking about compiler optimization. It is more of a conceptual question than programming and difference should have been pointed out. Thats what I did. Other points are obvious

Comment: C does not define how the `? :` is executed. If it did define some execution model, then I wouldn't get identical code from *non-optimizing* compiler pass.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you. I was not aware of it. I had not thought that I would learn from this question

Comment: I mean of course a compiler *can* compile `? :` into series of jumps, but you cannot reason it from the code itself.

Comment: That was the impression I had that it would evaluate to series of jumps. Ternary operator is inline if-else. Your answer is very helpful

Comment: It *can* turn into series of branches if you have *function calls*. And what C standard talks about is a sequence point at `?`; that the side effect of `a` must happen before the side effect of `b` or `c`, and `c`s side effect does not happen if a was true, b's side effects do not happen if `a` was false.

Comment: But having function calls as part of ? : will make it more like if-else. What I don't understand is that in which case it won't turn into jumps with function calls. Functions most probably would be in a different memory location making jumps inevitable